# MongoDB find with not it in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try to find all documents from collection if it _id is not in array.

This is my code:

```
warehouses.find(query, items).toArray(function (error, docs) {
    if (error) {
        error(error);
        return;
    }
    if (docs) {
        var material = db.collection('material');

        material.find({$nin: {'_id': docs[0].items}}, function (e, items) {
            if (error) {
                error(error);
                return;
            }
            success(items);

        });

    }

});
```

in material.find line, currentItems have two ObjectsID, but the return of find is empty..What is wrong?

Comment: The code `warehouses.findOne` only returns **one** item. So there is no **array** to `.forEach()` on.

Comment: yes, but when i do docs.item, i get the item field, and this contains an array, when i do db.collection('material'); the currentItems variable contains the _id for the query..
Please, read all the question and the code before reply..

Comment: I think you should declare `var currentItems = [];` inside the callback, just before the foreEach. Could change something (or not, I'm not sure)

Comment: @Vadorequest same result..the docs response is empty

Comment: Which one? ^^ Are you sure currentItems doesn't contains all your records? In this case there would have no result after the find (not in). What contains currentItems once filled?

Comment: The result of findOne query return an array with the _id for the next query.The material.find query with _id: {$nin: currentItems} params is empty, but currentItems have 3 ObjectId getted from previous query.

Comment: What I mean is that if currentItems contains all your `material` records then your `not in` request won't find any record left. Maybe the query actually works.

Comment: currentItems only contains 2 elements, and in material collection there are about 15 documents..

Comment: Not a **chat room** your question is flawed with basic approaches you can search "off-line" from here. Please do some research before posting. Otherwise If you actually had asked a real question, then you would have and answer by now.

Comment: Always reply me with the same, i was looking for awnser my question, i cant find anything and i ask here..Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related to event-loop feature of nodejs. Each callback function is executed parallelly. So, while the line that starts with`"material.find"` started to be executed,  probably

```
function (item, index) {
        currentItems[index] = item._id;
}
```

is still being executed. This is why you get an empty result. To achieve your goal, you should done all work in only one callback function. Follow these steps:

- select only ids in the first query(populate `currentItems` variable in the query). so, you can remove `doc.items.foreach....`
- Then call the the function `material.find....` inside callback function of the query.

Comment: I edit my code with your indications, but have same result, in success(docs) docs.items its empty.

Comment: Your query format is also wrong. Check `$nin` usage: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/. The code seems ok. Just make sure that docs[0].items is not empty and contains desired data.

Comment: One more tip. Don't change your question. If you want to add new code lines or comments, just append them to the end of question.